# Getting an ajax post data in php

Tags: php, jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/gateway/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {test : 'test'},
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function(){
    console.log('done');
});
```

Above is my AJAX post, below is my PHP:

```
var_dump($_POST['test']);
die();
```

The problem is, this fails to work (I get a NULL value) - why?

I know my call is getting to the PHP code as I can dump any old string:

```
var_dump('hello');
die();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST);` do you see anything there?

Comment: What happens on printing $_POST array?

Comment: It's just blank when printing

Comment: can you please try with -     data: {'test' : 'test'} Problem seems to be related to 'data'

Comment: I guess data is correct.... are you able to see 'test' in firebug console under parameters

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this `dataType: 'json'`. Your `$_POST['test']` is a string value, not a JSON string.

Comment: So your problem may be outside of the provided code in your question. Make sure that you sent the request with an exact `url`.

Answer (score 1):

The POST value that you are testing with is not JSON, it's a string.

Remove the

```
dataType: 'json',
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `dataType: "json"` within the AJAX request it means the expected response should be parsed as json, (not the outgoing POST, as others have said).

Heres is a stripped down copy&paste example, for you to build upon. Hope it helps

```
<?php 
//is it POST
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    // set var
    $test = isset($_POST['test']) ? $_POST['test'] : null;

    //do some logic - skip that bit ;p

    //was the request from AJAX, ok send back json
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //always a good idea
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        //json encode, notice the ABC, then look at the jQuery below
        die(json_encode(
            array('ABC' => 'From Response: '.$test)
        ));
    }
}
?>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var ajax = $.ajax({
        url: "./",
        type: "POST",
        data: {test : 'test'},
        dataType: "json"
    });
    ajax.done(function(data) {
        $("#result").html(data.ABC); /* << See data is an object */
    });
    ajax.fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        $("#result").html(xhr.responseText);
    });
});
</script>

<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if this is the issue, but `.done` is deprecated.  Additionally, as others mentioned, you are asking for json from the server and not receiving json.

Your code should look like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/gateway/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {test : 'test'},
    success: function () {console.log('done');}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend you my code. and please do check the following points.

1. check the location of the url you are giving. If it is in parent directory then you can access it using `../` and the most important thing give the extension of the file. like 'gateway.php'
2. and write success and failure function. It gives a better insight of what's going on.

   ```
       $.ajax({
       type:'POST', 
       url:'gateway',  
       data:{test:'test'},

       success: function(data){
           if(data)
           {
                   alert(data);
           }
       }, 
       failure: function(){
           alert(failed);
       }

   }) ;
   ```

comment if there are any errors

hope it helps :). If it does then don't forget to green it :P

Answer (score -1):

Or change PHP code

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
exit(json_encode(array('data' => 'Bla bla bla')));
```